# How do we rotate the wso2-apigw-errors.log file in the WSO2 API Manager gateway as the file size is too large

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The wso2-apigw-errors.log file in the WSO2 API Manager gateway is too large and we would like to rotate this log file as it done for the wso2carbon.log file on a daily basis.

Is there some value that has to be added or modified in the log4j.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

You have use

```
org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
```

instead of

```
org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
```

like below in

```
<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties
```

file

```
log4j.appender.ERROR_LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
```

Comment: Is restart of wso2-am required after changing configuration as above ?

Comment: Yes, you need to restart.